# Cucumber : How to skip subsequent steps and exit out of the scenario without failing the step / scenario?

Tags: c#, cucumber, gherkin

I have had my feature file in Cucumber and am using Given, When, Then syntax(Gherkin) to write my scenarios in it and have the corresponding steps in the Step Definition file.
I have a scenario, where I am checking if a particular data set exists(which is part of my Given step ) then continue with my next steps for "Then", "And" etc
But if it's not, then it should skip rest of the steps and exit out of the Step Definition file without failing the scenario.
Can someone please advise if this is supported in Cucumber? If yes, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JUnits `Assume` or TestNG's `SkipException` to mark a test as skipped if a specific assumption fails. Skipped tests are not considered failures.

From https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/junit

> Through [Assume](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html) JUnit provides:
>
> > a set of methods useful for stating assumptions about the conditions in which a test is meaningful. A failed assumption does not mean the code is broken, but that the test provides no useful information. The default JUnit runner skips tests with failing assumptions. Custom runners may behave differently.
>
> The Cucumber runner supports Assume and will marked skipped scenarios as skipped.

From https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/testng

> Cucumber provides limited support for [SkipException](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/SkipException.html).
>
> - Throwing a SkipException results in both Cucumber and TestNG marking the test as skipped.
> - Throwing a subclass of SkipException results in Cucumber marking the test as failed and TestNG marking the test as skipped.

Comment: Thanks . I think "Assume" option with 'Before' tag would work the best in my case. But the only thing I am working on Cucumber in Visual Studio using C#. I am not able to figure out if Assume is supported in C#. Any idea?

Comment: You should tag your question with C# and Specflow instead of cucumber-jvm.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, enclose your lines of code within try-catch block and ensure no assertions in catch block.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will have to create a custom exception for this one. Because I wanted to check this in the beginning and then continue/exit.